# 2D arrays and dynamic arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a class which just contains a 1D array of set size (17): However this array needs to be for every monitor that a user has and I am unsure whether to simply set say and array of size 10 limiting the user, or whether to try a more dynamic approach.

Excerpt from `ScreenArray.h`:

```
private:
    unsigned long pixelArray[17];
```

I would like advise to which method(s) will work best for my problem and how would I go about constructing / allocating and accessing it?

EDIT: The array (Or the 2D part of the array) *preferably* dynamic to the size of the monitors currently connected. This contains the 1D array of set size 17.

Comment: Since I assume the number of monitors to be variable I would recommend using something more dynamic, like `std::vector`

Comment: The question is unclear to me. `this array needs to be for every monitor that a user has and I am unsure whether to simply set say and array of size 10 limiting the user` Do you want an array of size 17 per each monitor? Or do you mean that the array must be the length of the number of monitors (i.e. dynamic, not static)? Or do you want the array be of static size but limit the usable size dynamically?

Comment: I have to agree with @user2079303, this isn't very clear.

Answer (score 0):

As UnholySheep stated out, vector is a great tool to use in this situation:

- Variable size;
- Out of range protection;
- Automatic memory management;
- ...

The only drawback I see may be a loss in performance, but because your vector is so small, you won't even be able to measure it, so this doesn't count.

You can use it like so:

```
// You'll need this one
#include <vector>

// Create you vector
// Replace TYPE with the type of it's members.
std::vector< TYPE > pixelArray;

// Add members to it
pixelArray.push_back( MEMBER );

// Access it as usual
pixelArray[n];
```

Comment: What about those of us who aren't woolly animals from hell??

Comment: I suppose that was a joke but I didn't get it xD
What are you really trying to say?

Comment: Read your first sentence ;)

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry UnholySheep. I didn't mean to use you like that :D